# Change class of elements in a list and loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, loops

I'm having a bit of trouble with a script. I have the basic idea, but cannot translate it into code.

Here's what it's supposed to accomplish:

I am using Animate.CSS, and I have the following list:

```
<ul class="display" id="imagens-home">
  <li class="invisivel"><img src="img/teste/lanche-1.jpg/></li>
  <li class="invisivel"><img src="img/teste/lanche-2.jpg/></li>
  <li class="invisivel"><img src="img/teste/lanche-3.jpg/></li>
  <li class="invisivel"><img src="img/teste/lanche-4.jpg/></li>    
</ul>
```

I want to make a script that will:

1. Remove the .invisivel (display:none) class from an item;
2. Add the .fadeInLeft class to it;
3. Stay visible for about three seconds;
4. Replace .fadeInLeft with .zoomOut;
5. Make the element hidden again;
6. Repeat for next item on the list;

I managed to find a way to enable the FadeIn animation, then after it ends, enable FadeOut and make the div invisible again, with the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationIn = 'animated fadeInLeft';
  var animationOut = 'animated zoomOut';
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

  $('#imagens-home>li').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('invisivel').addClass(animationIn).on(animationEnd, function(){
      $(this).removeClass(animationIn).addClass(animationOut).on(animationEnd, function(){
        $(this).removeClass(animationOut).addClass('invisivel')
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="display" id="imagens-home">
  <li class="invisivel">0</li>
    <li class="invisivel">1</li>
  <li class="invisivel">2</li>
    <li class="invisivel">3</li>    
</ul>
```

But I cannot find a way to make it loop through the list items. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I dont get the problem. You're looping through the list items, what is the thing that is happening and the thing that is not happening yet?. Could you create a jsfiddle example?

Comment: @Aschab or click the `<>` in the SO editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want each element to animate completely, before the next one starts animating.

Instead of using a loop, which will start all the animations essentially in parallel, you can use a recursive function to iterate through the elements by animating the next one when the previous one is done animating.

```js
var animationIn = 'animated fadeInLeft';
var animationOut = 'animated zoomOut';
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

function animate($items, idx) {
  if (idx >= $items.length) return; // no more items, stop animating 

  var $current = $items.eq(idx);
  $current.removeClass('invisivel').addClass(animationIn).on(animationEnd, function() {
    $current.removeClass(animationIn).addClass(animationOut).on(animationEnd, function() {
      $current.removeClass(animationOut).addClass('invisivel');
      animate($items, idx + 1); // try animating the next item
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  animate($('#imagens-home>li'), 0);
});
```

```css
.invisivel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="display" id="imagens-home">
  <li class="invisivel">0</li>
  <li class="invisivel">1</li>
  <li class="invisivel">2</li>
  <li class="invisivel">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great! The only issue I'm finding is that the images appear one under the other, even if the previous one is hidden. Also, how can I trigger it again once it ends?

Comment: You might need to float, display: inline, or absolutely position the images, I'm not sure which without testing. As far as repeating again when it ends, you can just set `idx = 0` in the `if` statement (when it crosses over `$items.length`) instead of returning.

Comment: Float, display and position did the trick. Setting idx=0 however loops twice, skipping the animations, and stops looping. I messed with the code all I could, but couldn't find a reason for it.